# EndSale function in Solidity fails

Tags: erc-20, presale

I have the following solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "./DappToken.sol";

contract DappTokenSale {
    address payable public admin;
    DappToken public tokenContract;
    uint256 public tokenPrice;
    uint256 public tokensSold;

    event Sell(address _buyer, uint256 _amount);

    constructor (DappToken _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) public {
        admin = msg.sender;
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
    }

    function multiply(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
        require(y == 0 || (z = x * y) / y == x);
    }

    function buyTokens(uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable {
        require(msg.value == multiply(_numberOfTokens, tokenPrice));
        require(tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _numberOfTokens);
        require(tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens));

        tokensSold += _numberOfTokens;

        emit Sell(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens);
    }

    function endSale() public {
        require(msg.sender == admin);
        require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))));

        // UPDATE: Let's not destroy the contract here
        // Just transfer the balance to the admin
        //admin.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Everything works except for the endSale() function. When I call it, it throws an error. I can't understand what is the problem. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling it from the admin address? Does the token's `transfer` function return true?

Comment: yes, I'm calling it with my admin address. I get this: Uncaught:
StatusError: Transaction: 0xf.... exited with an error (status 0).
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:0:19
   hijackedStack: 'StatusError: Transaction: ....exited with an error (status 0). \n' +
    '     Please check that the transaction:\n' + ..... (edited )